# Error converting file path

Tags: android, path, base64

I am having problems especially converting **path Uri** from `KITKAT` to Base64 format. The code works well for all the devies with API 18 and lower. Can someone please help.

```
11-29 09:57:44.407: I/FILE_URI(23833): content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A6108
```

This is the content that is returned from the **path Uri**.

The following is the Base64 conversion code:

```
public void getGalleryDetails(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {


    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    byte[] bytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try{
        while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bytes = output.toByteArray();

    encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.i("ENCODED", encodedImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `KITKAT` has some other mechanism of handling documents now, I used the following:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Picture"),
                            FROM_GALLERY);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, FROM_GALLERY);
                }
```